# consequence of the Riesz representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, proof-explanation

let $f$ be a non-trivial linear functional on a Hilbert space $H$

we denote the dual space of $H$ by $H^*$

then according to the Riesz representation theorem there exists a unique $v$ such that  $f(u) = \langle {u,v} \rangle \;\; \forall u \in H$

now in the book I'm using in order to prove that $||f||_{H^*} = ||v||_H$

the author proceeded as follows :

$$||f|| = \sup_{||u|| = 1 }|f(u)| =  \sup_{||u|| = 1 }|\langle {u,v} \rangle| \leq  \sup_{||u|| = 1 }||u|||v|| = ||v|| $$

$$ ||v||^2 = \langle {v,v} \rangle = |f(v)|  \leq ||f|| ||v||$$

thus, we have the equality $||f|| = ||v||$

I have 2 questions :

- which norm did he use to prove the first inequality ? (I've checked that it's in fact a norm. I'm just curious to know its name)
- I'm aware that all norms on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space are equivalent but here $H$ can have an infinite dimension so is it still enough to use a specific norm to prove a general statement ?

Comment: $\|f\|$ uses the dual norm, which is an operator norm. I don't understand your second question, the statement was an equality of norms, which was proven.

Comment: @bjorne is it the only norm that can be defined on the dual space ?

because if there can be another one it doesn't mean that the equality would still hold. thanks for the answer btw

Comment: The standard norm on $H^*$ is defined by $||f||=\sup_{||u||=1}|f(u)|$. That's the norm the author is referring to. I don't understand your question either. Yes, there are other norms on $H^*$, and those inequalities would nnt work for the other norms. So what? He's  not saying anything about those other norms. Nobody said anything about anything holding for every norm on $H^*$. No, we can't use a specific norm to prove a general statement about norms. That doesn't come up here - we use a specific norm to prove something about that specific norm.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich thank you so much. now I get it.

I initially thought that $\|f\|_{H^*} $ meant for any norm defined on $H^*$